# How sprintf works in C

Tags: c

Linux Kernel = 2.6.32-41-generic #94-Ubuntu
Language : C

Code Snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char buf[5];
    int index = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < 5; index++ )
    {
        sprintf(buf,"sud_%d", index);
        printf("for index = %d\n",index);
        printf("buf = %s\n",buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Question1 : Why the above code snippet goes into loop while executing the above code?
Question2 : Does sprintf requires its last bit of the target buffer to be filled with 0 or '\0' ?

if I made the buffer size 6 (buf[6]) in the above code, it works fine.

can anyone please let me know the reason of this behavior?

Regards,
Sudhansu

Answer (score 4):

Because undefined behavior.

The output buffer `buf` is only 5 characters big, but the first call to `sprintf()` will generate the string `"sud_0"`, which requires 6 characters due to the terminator. It then writes outside of `buf`, triggering undefined behavior. Use `snprintf()`.

`snprintf()` doesn't "require" the last character to be filled with anything *before* you call it, but it will make sure it's set to `'\0'` *after*  the call has completed. This is because it aims to build a complete and valid C string in the given buffer, and thus it must make sure the string is properly terminated.

It's hard (and some would say pointless) to reason about undefined behavior, but I suspect that what happens is that the 6th character written into `buf` overflows into `index`, writing the first byte to 0. If you're on a little-endian system, this will be the same as doing `index &= ~255`. Since the value of `index` is just supposed to be between 0 and 5, it's reset to 0 which causes the loop to go on for ever.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for answering the question, can you be please more specific, why this looping happens.
I have added a single integer to the posted program and it seems to be working as desired.
So the question is, Is it a memory alignment issue?
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char buf[5];
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < 5; index++ )
    {
        sprintf(buf,"sud_%d", index);
        printf("for index = %d\n",index);
        printf("buf = %s\n",buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
Regards,
Sudhansu

Answer (score 3):

You are writing outside declared buffer. That is undefined behavior.

Your `char buf[5];` is too small. You require at least 6 chars for "sud_0" because of the `'\0'` terminator.